# jqgrid inline editing using "actions" formatter - Ajax Call Setup

Tags: json, ajax, jqgrid, action, formatter

### Questions

I am currently trying to use the action formatter for updating data in the grid.

1. On pressing save icon - all 3 events are being triggered, not sure how this is possible. Both success & error are writing the in the log.
2. Is there an onSubmit event (when pressing save icon)?
3. How can i view what is passed to the url where my editing method is?

```js
   
                {
                    label: " ",
                    name: "actions",
                    width: 100,
                    formatter: "actions",
                    formatoptions: {

                        keys: true,
                        editbutton: true,
                        delbutton: false,
                        restoreAfterError: true,
                        serializeRowData: function (data) { return JSON.stringify(data); },
                        editOptions: {
                            url: 'myurl',
                            ajaxEditOptions: {

                                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                                mtype: "POST",
                                datatype: 'json'

                            }
                            
                        },
                        onSuccess: function (jqXHR) {
                            console.log(jqXHR.statusText);
                        },
                        onError: function (rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {                 
                            console.log(jqXHR.statusText);
                        },
                        afterSave: function (rowid) {
                           
                        },


                    },
                    search: false
                }
```

Comment: You use wrong options (see `serializeRowData`, `ajaxEditOptions`, `restoreAfterError`,... inside of `formatoptions`). What editing mode you want to use (inline editing or form editing)? You write about inline editing, but uses some options of form editing and you place the options on the wrong place. Which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid you want to use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in some version <=4.7)?

Comment: Hi Oleg, 
Yes you're absolutely right i mixed them up by mistake. I am using inline editing, i removed the form editing lines and corrected placement. Ajax call went through now and it's working :) 

I am using the free version v4.8.2.

Thanks for your feedback, much appreciated ^^

Comment: You are welcome! The version 4.8.2 **can't be used for free**, like other Guriddo version >=4.7.1. If you opens the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` you will see the name "Guriddo jqGrid JS". You can find the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I develop **alternative fork**: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), the current version is 4.13.3, which I provides for free like it was in all jqGrid in version <=4.7.